# MSSQL: Append String from Select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'd like to add a text to nvarchar field based on a select from another table.

When I try this I get the following error:
The multi-part identifier "employees.desc" could not be bound

```
UPDATE
    employees
SET
    employees.desc = employees.desc + ', ' + c.title
FROM
    employees AS e
    INNER JOIN company AS c
        ON e.dept=c.orgcode
WHERE e.dept IS NOT NULL
```

If I just set a new title without appending to the existing one using

```
employees.desc = c.title
```

it works ok. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you also dont have table alias `o`

Comment: sorry, this error is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-write it like this:

```
UPDATE
    e
SET
    desc = e.desc + ', ' + c.title
FROM
    employees AS e
    INNER JOIN company AS c
        ON e.dept=c.orgcode
WHERE e.dept IS NOT NULL
```

There is no need to explicitly specify which table you are referring to in your `SET` clause. I.e. you can write `SET desc = ...` instead of `SET e.desc = ...`. It's already specified in your `UPDATE` clause which table you are updating.

Comment: What if there was also a condition like c.FoundingDate > '2012-01-01'? I have never heard of this that where clause has any say in which table gets updated.

Comment: What are you referring to here? I have not mentioned anywhere in my answer that the WHERE clause has any say in which table gets updated. Perhaps you misread something?

Comment: @TanveerBadar Please explain yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the aliases from the FROM/JOIN

```
UPDATE
    employees
SET
    employees.desc = e.desc + ', ' + c.title
FROM
    employees AS e
    INNER JOIN company AS c
    ON e.dept=c.orgcode
WHERE e.deptIS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your query be this instead?

```
UPDATE
    employees
SET
    employees.desc = e.desc + ', ' + c.title
FROM
    employees AS e
    INNER JOIN company AS c
        ON e.dept=c.orgcode
WHERE e.deptIS NOT NULL
```

There's no table named o in your original query.